Browse kubernetes container's filesystem with midnight commander?
Assuming a kubernetes container has bash or similar installed, is it possible to use midnight commander (e.g. shell link, sftp link, ...) to browse the container's filesystem?

Yes it's fully possible, here I tried Shell Link into a libvirt container with mc installed:

and here is a screenshot where I tried it with a container not having it installed:

and it worked with both

Nice. Would you mind sharing more details about how you got it to work? I see at the top right vagrant@192.168.56.112:22?

@Sparkler I used a vagrant container with libvirt, this link can help: https://vagrant-libvirt.github.io/vagrant-libvirt/, to mc into another device this link helps: https://4sysops.com/archives/midnight-commander-remote-connect-via-shell-link-copy-files-over-ssh-and-sftp-link-using-fish-and-public-key-authentication/

Sounds like you're ssh-ing into a VM, not into a (docker) container. Updated question.
